# Activity has leaked window at alertDialog show() method

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am getting window leak error at runtime because of using an AlertDialog.

I have pointed out the error line in the code below:

**Stacktrace:**

```
08-18 02:48:04.489  28893-28893/? E/WindowManager﹕ Activity com.ms.ha.fragment.FirstActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{52e58540 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-1026,585} that was originally added here
    android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.ms.ha.fragment.FirstActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{52e58540 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-1026,585} that was originally added here
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:345)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:239)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
            at com.ms.ha.fragment.TourGuideLoadURLFragment$WebAppInterface.moveToNextScreen(TourGuideLoadURLFragment.java:116)
            at android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeMouseClick(Native Method)
            at android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeMouseClick(Native Method)
            at android.webkit.WebViewCore.access$6800(WebViewCore.java:59)
            at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub.dispatchWebKitEvent(WebViewCore.java:1793)
            at android.webkit.WebViewInputDispatcher.dispatchWebKitEvent(WebViewInputDispatcher.java:689)
            at android.webkit.WebViewInputDispatcher.dispatchWebKitEvents(WebViewInputDispatcher.java:639)
            at android.webkit.WebViewInputDispatcher.access$800(WebViewInputDispatcher.java:78)
            at android.webkit.WebViewInputDispatcher$WebKitHandler.handleMessage(WebViewInputDispatcher.java:1153)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:814)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

**FirstActivity.java:**

```
 public class FirstActivity extends FragmentActivity  implements View.OnClickListener{

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_tour_guide_web);
  .......
  .......

   webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");

 }


    public class WebAppInterface {
        Context mContext;

        /**
         * Instantiate the interface and set the context
         */
        WebAppInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        /**
         * Intent - Move to next screen
         */

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void moveToNextScreen() {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    context);

            // set title
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");

            // set dialog message
            alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage("Click yes!")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                            Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // if this button is clicked, just close
                            // the dialog box and do nothing
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();  --->leak window error

        }

    }

  }
```

I don't know how to solve this issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added
Check out this.

Comment: It occurs when you try to show / dismiss an ALertDialog created and showing in one Activity and dismissing in another Activity.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You get error because `ProgressDialog` is running while your `Activity` is destroyed. You should dismiss dialog before starting new `Activity`.

```
.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
      if (alertDialog != null && alertDialog.isShowing()) {
          alertDialog.dismiss();
      }
      Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
      startActivity(i);
  }
});
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Try code i have edited in answer. dismiss dialog or finish activity when new activity starts

Comment: That means that your main thread doesn't know about your changes and then when it takes action your main thread finds that it is already different object. 
try call your function in main thread.`
     runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            //your function
                        }
                    });`

Comment: but in that case, stacktrace should have leak on `onStop()` or `onDestroy()`, isn't so?

Answer (score 16):

Dismiss the alertDialog in onPause() method. i.e. call alertDialog.dismiss()

Note : WindowLeaked exceptions are occured usually if dialogs are not dismissed before Activity is ended.

Answer (score 5):

You can also get a WindowLeaked exception if you're not in the UI thread when attempting to show the dialog. Easy fix:

```
this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // show dialog here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You must need to dismiss/cancel your dialog once activity is finishing. It occurs usually if dialogs are not dismissed before Activity is ended.

Answer (score -12):

Check in your manifest if you have setted internet permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score -14):

I don't know does this help but at me problem's were causing multidex.
At build.gradle

```
multiDexEnabled false
```

Comment: No, multidex doesn´t apply here! =0